# Register isn't creating new users in database

Tags: php, mysql, session

Whenn i will signup in signup.php... The problem is that when I press submit, the credentials are not inserted into the database. Can someone please help me out? Whenn i click on submit thenn i don't get error but succesfully registered.. My php version in directadmin is 5.1.

This is my code of my signup.php:

```
<head>

<title>.:: NitanCrime ::.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<?php /* ------------------------- */

  include("yep.php");
    if(check_login()) {
        print "<html>";
        print "<head>";
        print "<LINK href='images/mxstyle.css' type=text/css rel=stylesheet>";
        print "</head>";
        print "<body style='background: #grey; margin: 100px;'>";
        print "<table align='center' width=100%>";
        print "<tr>Je bent al ingelogd</tr>";

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `[online]` WHERE `login`='{$_COOKIE['login']}' AND `validate`='{$_COOKIE['validate']}' AND `IP`='{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}'");
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
    unset($_SESSION['IP']);
    unset($_SESSION['data']);

print <<<ENDHTML
</table>


}
</body>


</html>
ENDHTML;
  exit;
  }
$inboxchek =1;
  if(isset($_GET['v']) && ($_GET['v'] == 1 || $_GET['v'] == 2)) {
    setcookie("v",$_GET['v'],time()+24*60*60*365,"/","");
    $_COOKIE['v']                       = $_GET['v'];
  }

  if(isset($_GET['baas'])) {
    setcookie("baas",$_GET['baas'],time()+24*60*60*365,"/","");
    $_COOKIE['baas']                    = $_GET['baas'];
  }

    if(!isset($_GET['baas'])) {
    setcookie("baas","",time()+24*60*60*365,"/","");
    $_COOKIE['baas']                    = "";
  }

  if(isset($_COOKIE['login'],$_COOKIE['validate'])) {
    setcookie("login",$_COOKIE['login'],time()+24*60*60,"/","");
    setcookie("validate",$_COOKIE['validate'],time()+24*60*60,"/","");
  }

  mysql_query("UPDATE `[users]` SET `online`=NOW() WHERE `login`='{$data->login}'");
  $ref = $_GET['x'];
  $dbres                                = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `[users]` WHERE `activated`=1");
  $members                              = mysql_num_rows($dbres);
  $dbres                                = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `[users]` WHERE `level`=100");
  $paymembers                           = mysql_num_rows($dbres);

  $dbres                                = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `[users]` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`online`) < 300");

  $online                               = mysql_num_rows($dbres);
  $chek = mysql_query("SELECT `login` FROM `[users]` WHERE `login`='$ref'");
  $ok = mysql_num_rows($chek);

  function ip() {   
        if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) { 
            return getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'); 
        } elseif(getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')) {   
            return getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'); 
        } else { 
            return getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'); 
        } 
  } 
  $baas         = $_COOKIE['baas'];
  $IP                                           = ip(); 
  $login                                        = $_POST['login'];
  $pass                                         = $_POST['pass'];
  $passconfirm                          = $_POST['passconfirm'];
  $email                                        = $_POST['email'];
  $type                                         = $_POST['type']; 
  ${"select$type"}                      = "selected";
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $Dupe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `[users]` WHERE `IP`='{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}' AND `level`='2'");
  $dU = mysql_num_rows($Dupe);
  if($dU >=2){ echo " Je Mag Slechts 1 Account per Ip Adres Hebben! $dU"; exit; }
    $message                                    = Array(
        "Je login mag alleen A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _ en - hebben",
        "Vul een geldig e-mail adres in",
        "Selecteer een type crimineel",
        "Er bestaat al iemand met die login",
        "Er is al iemand met die e-mail");

    $msgnum                                     = -1;
    if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+$/',$login) == 0)
      $msgnum                                   = 0;
    if(preg_match('/^.+@.+\..+$/',$email) == 0)
      $msgnum                                   = 1;
    else {
      $dbres                                    = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `[users]` WHERE `login`='$login'");
      if(mysql_num_rows($dbres) > 0)
        $msgnum                                 = 3;
      $dbres                                    = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `[users]` WHERE `email`='$email'");
      if(mysql_num_rows($dbres) > 0)
        $msgnum                                 = 4;
          $clientIP                             = $IP;
          $forwardedFor                         = ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] != "") ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
          $forwardedFor                         = preg_replace('/, .+/','',$forwardedFor);
      if($ref !='' AND  $ok == 0){ echo " Foutive Refferal $ref "; exit; }
      if($msgnum == -1) {

$code                                   = rand(100000,999999);
$passs                                  = rand(100000,999999);
$land = rand(1,4);
          mysql_query("UPDATE `[users]` SET `land`='1' WHERE `login`='$data->login'");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `[users]`(`signup`,`login`,`pass`,`regIP`,`email`,`land`) values(NOW(),'$login',MD5('$passs'),'$IP','$email','$land')");
        mysql_query("UPDATE `[users]` SET `cash`=`cash`+'10000',`ervaring`=`ervaring`+'500' WHERE `login`='$ref'");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `[messages]`(`time`,`IP`,`forwardedFor`,`from`,`to`,`subject`,`message`) values(NOW(),'{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}','$forwardedFor',' NitanCrime ','$ref','Refferal','Je Maakte $login lid op NitanCrime! Je  verdiende 10,000')");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `[temp]`(login,IP,code,area,time) values('$login','$IP',$code,'$land','signup',NOW())");
        $id                                     = mysql_insert_id();
        mail($email,"NitanCrime Aanmelding","Hey!\n Welkom op NitanCrime\n\nBedankt voor u registratie. U kunt nu inloggen!\n\nHier is u informatie:\n\nGebruikersnaam: $login\nWachtwoord: $passs\n\nOnthoud u wachtwoord goed, deze kan niet meer achterhaald worden. Deze kan echter wel veranderd worden!\n\nVriendelijke groeten,\n\n NitanCrime","From: NitanCrime <aanmelding@nitancrime.com>\n");
      }
    }
  }

/* ------------------------- */ ?>




<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<body>
<?
if($msgnum != -1) {
        if(isset($msgnum) && $msgnum != -1)
                print "<td><center>{$message[$msgnum]}</center></td>\n";
if($_GET['x'] == "") {
  $baas = "(Geen)";
}
else {
  $baas = $_GET['x'];
}      
print <<<ENDHTML

<table  style="position: absolute; left: 270px; top: 148px;" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<form method="post">

<BR><BR><BR>
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">
 <tr><td align=center colspan="2" class=main><b>Aanmelden</b></td></tr>
<tr><td class=sub width=100><font color=black>Gebruikersnaam:</font></td>
<td class=sub><INPUT name="login" type="text" VALUE='' maxlength="16" style="width: 150;"></td></tr>
<tr><td class=sub width=100><font color=black>Email:</font></td> 
<td class=sub><INPUT name="email" type="text" VALUE='' style="width: 150;"></td></tr>                                                                                                             

<td class=sub colspan="2" align=center><input type="submit" name="submit" style=" height: 20; width: 110;" value="Aanmelden"></td>
</table>
</tr></form>

ENDHTML;
    }
    else
      print "  Je bent aangemeld!, Er is een e-mail gestuurd naar $email met Je wachtwoord! <b>Check u Ongewenste Mail!</b>\n";




?> 

</BODY>
</HTML>

<? mysql_close($mysql); ?>
```

Comment: stop using mysql_*

Comment: why do your table names all have `[]`

Comment: where did you get this code from?

Comment: I know it but this website is only for me self and not for others. it's very old source. And i will fix it..

Comment: `[]` makes me think SQL Server, not MySQL…

Comment: @saahxo, that's no excuse for poor security. Get in the habit of using modern libraries and APIs now.

Comment: In my sql is called [users]

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what [] is for or {} is for, but your '' and "" are messing each other up.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `online` WHERE `login`='$username' LIMIT 1";
mysql_query($sql);
```

The above piece should work fine, the problem comes from when accessing arrays in php 5.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `online` WHERE `login`='$_COOKIE['login']' LIMIT 1";
mysql_query($sql);
```

The above line won't work because of the double ''.  To get around this try.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `online` WHERE`login`='".$_COOKIE['online']." LIMIT 1";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Use the double quotes to exit the str, so you can insert your variable.

Hope this helps,

Side note: I'm not exactly sure if it is spacing, but it looks like you have an open if statement somewhere in there.

---

Also if you are using php 5, mysqli should work just fine.  You should still change it mysqli.  In many cases, it is faster and more secure. There isn't any more work.

Comment: What do you mean with str,?